# Estoy intentando correr java en visual studio pero aparece esto This path is not pointing to a JDK

Tags: java, vscode

Desde que instale [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) he tenido este error y abro el archivo `settings.json`
solo tiene escrito esto

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Viow Arabian - Mix",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-great-icons"
    "java.home":"/home/asus/Descargas/jre-8u241-linux-x64/jre1.8.0_241"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) Buster 10, me sirvió:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

En visual studio, para configurar el Java Runtime ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, para buscarlo) puse en settings.json:

```
"java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/",
```

Seguido, recargué el editor y me funcionó sin ningún error. Esta [página](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1092) me ayudo.

Comment: Como verás él usa [tag:java-8], tal vez sería bueno que le contaras un poco acerca de la diferencia entre `openjdk-8-jdk` y `openjdk-8`

Comment: No estoy seguro la verdad. Intenté investigar pero lo que aparece con más frecuencia es la diferencia entre Oracle JDK y OpenJDK, es la misma, no cierto?

Comment: De igual forma, cuento con java-8-openjdk-amd64 instalado en mi /usr/lib/jvm, pero no lo utilizo. El único que utilizo es el openjdk-11-jdk.

Comment: tradicionalmente uno se equivocaba en ubuntu porque la opción de instalar java desde la store de canonical te instalaba openjdk-8 que no traía el jdk, para Java9+ ya no tienes ese problema porque el jre viene con el jdk.

Answer (score 0):

En VSCode, tienes que pulsar las teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> y, en el cuadro de dialogo escribir "Configure Java Runtime".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acto seguido, configurar las rutas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo tengo así y me funciona (de hecho, tengo instalado OpenJDK).